# What's an appropriate html element/attribute to invisibly annotate a fieldset for screenreaders?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm working with a fieldset that allows the user to answer a multiple choice question that is displayed prominently elsewhere on the page, but separately from the fieldset.

e.g.

```
<div>
  <div id="main">
    <h3> What is the capitol of France? </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar"> 
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose One:</legend>
      <!-- radio buttons -->
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to include the question text in the fieldset's `legend` because it would be redundant for sighted users. But I need to include the question in the fieldset so it's obvious to a screenreader that the question is associated with the fieldset.

Any links/insight would be much appreciated. I've done a fair bit of googling and asking around to colleagues and not found any clearcut answer.

Note: The html above is not the actual code. The real-life code for `#main` and `#sidebar` is deeply nested and fairly complex. So it's not practical to re-arrange the html to combine the displayed question with the fieldset.

Comment: Using a legend *instead of* an `h3` would make the most sense. Then style the legend to look the way you want.

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. The question (h3) is in a completely separate region of the page from the fieldset. It's displayed prominently however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `aria-describedby`

```
<div>
  <div id="main">
    <h3 id="question"> What is the capitol of France? </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar"> 
    <fieldset aria-describedby="question">
      <legend>Choose One:</legend>
      <!-- radio buttons -->
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute):

> The aria-describedby attribute is used to indicate the IDs of the elements that describe the object. It is used to establish a relationship between widgets or groups and text that described them. This is very similar to aria-labelledby: a label describes the essence of an object, while a description provides more information that the user might need.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was just reading http://www.last-child.com/legend-aria-describedby/ and it also made me think aria-describedby might be the most appropriate: `Sometimes we are not able to rebuild a form from scratch and have to work with a page that uses table layouts or some other set of code that makes it impractical to use the proper HTML coding. The aria-describedby attribute can help us restore the legend’s semantic value. `

Comment: I'd prefer `aria-labelledby`: `<fieldset role="group" aria-labelledby="question">`.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine Interesting -- can you say why?

Comment: Because of [this effect](https://www.aaron-gustafson.com/notebook/aria-quicktip-labelledby-vs-describedby/). Namely: the `labelledby` is read *before* the field, and `describedby` is read *after* it. And I'd want my SR to say "Question group". More than that, I find description semantically less appropriate as it should be something lengthy and chatty, like "This is a question I would like you to answer because of..." and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Note that if you use `aria-labelledby` you also have to set and include the `id` of the `legend` element (eg. `aria-labelledby="question idLegend"`) in order for it to be read